# Getting a 'random' value from a module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

Let's say I have a file that looks like this:

```
var random_nr = Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length);
var x = array[random_nr];
// do some things

exports.random_array_member = x
```

Now, if I 'require' this in another file, I will always get the same result as long as I don't restart my server, presumably because of caching?

What is the best way to run this code and get a random  value, while not including the code into my main file?

Comment: put it in/return it from a functional closure and call that function in your external file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have shown is only executed *once*. The result from that code is then stored as a variable, ready to be exported to whatever file needs it.

Instead, you need to "call" the code at the moment you need a random variable:

```
exports.random_array_member = function(){
    var random_nr = Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length);
    return array[random_nr];
}
```

Now, instead of accessing `exports.random_array_member`, you call `exports.random_array_member()` in your other files.

Comment: @degr: the array isn't the issue. The problem is that, when the server starts, the OP's code is executed, _once_, and a random array entry is stored to `random_array_member`. You want a random entry every time you access `random_array_member`, though.

Answer (score 2):

Lets play with [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

**random.js**

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

module.exports = {
  get random_array_member() {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)]
  }
}
```

**consumer.js**

```
var r = require('./random')

console.log(r.random_array_member)
console.log(r.random_array_member)
console.log(r.random_array_member)
```